# Voyager doesn't show images because of exists() function

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

I have a blog project created using Laravel, It works fine on my localhost, I uploaded the project and converted it to work on a shared host, and this is not my first time doing this, after uploading the project and the database, Everything works fine, I mean when opening the blog I can see my posts (**WITH PICTURES**) and categories and everything, **BUT** in the Voyager CPanel I can't see images, so I picked the admin logo as an example, In the database it contains this name (`settings/January2018/PnrVRpff94865gfxeZ0gt.png`) and the Voyager sideBar Blade code for this image is this :

```
<?php $admin_logo_img = Voyager::setting('admin_icon_image', ''); ?>
@if($admin_logo_img == '')
    <img src="{{ voyager_asset('images/logo-icon-light.png') }}" alt="Logo Icon">
@else
    <img src="{{ Voyager::image($admin_logo_img) }}" alt="Logo Icon">
@endif
```

and the result on chrome is this :

```
<img src="" alt="Logo Icon">
```

So I went to the `Voyager::image()` function :

```
public function image($file, $default = '')
    {
        if (!empty($file) && Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->exists($file)) {
            return Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->url($file);
        }

        return $default;
    }
```

And I did my tests and here is the results in this logo case :

`empty($file)` Return False (Good)

`Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->exists($file)` Return False (**Bad**)

`Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->url($file)` Return the Correct URL (Good)

Knowing that `config('voyager.storage.disk')` Return "public" and the filesystems disks config is untouched.

As you see the problem in the `Voyager::image()` Function, So please help me solve this problem in the right way.

**Update :**

I tried changing the Voyager::image() function in the /vendor/tcg/voyager/src folder To :

```
public function image($file, $default = '')
    {
        //Bad Solution
        return Storage::disk(config('voyager.storage.disk'))->url($file);
    }
```

and it worked so well, but as you see it's a bad solution, And I need a right one, So please help.